# understanding dns under systemd/networkmanager

Tags: ubuntu, dns, networkmanager, systemd-networkd, systemd-resolved

I am not understanding why my pc wasn't able to resolve names until I manually deleted a stale `nmcli device` entry.

---

Description/steps:

ubuntu 22.04 desktop, which uses `network-manager` and `systemd-resolved`.  I had a vpn installed, with "block connectivity outside of VPN" enabled.  Was having connectivity issues (specifically failure to resolve any names *i believe*). I disabled the "killswitch" in the VPN app, and uninstalled the VPN, and rebooted.

I was able to ping multiple ip's (including my intended dns server address 1.1.1.1, and a current IP of google.com)  But `nslookup` could not resolve any hostnames.  I *could* successfully `dig @1.1.1.1 google.com` as well.

My limited understand suggested that if i had:

- a valid interface `ip addr` with an IP on the expected subnet
- a valid default `ip route` to an IP on that subnet,
- and dns server of `1.1.1.1` in `Network Manager`

  - as shown on the NM gui - `/etc/resolve.conf` points to a server on localhost, `systemd-resolvd`
  - but note i see no `1.1.1.1` text *anywhere* in `/etc/systemd/` before or after the fix

then this (dns) "should be working".  Not so, obviously.

After some poking, i found a stale device in `nmcli d`, of type `dummy` and state `connected` which by it's name must have been created by the (now uninstalled) VPN app.  In case it is significant, this entry was 2nd, below the correct/expected connected wifi device.

deleting this nmcli `device` caused dns (`nslookup`, and programs such as browser), to resume working(resolving).  Specifically, from a fresh reboot I did `nslookup ...` (failed to resolve), then `nmcli connection delete ...`, then `nslookup ...` works.  No other changes / logout / etc.

---

Question:

Where should I have known to look to understand that this stale nmcli connection was the issue / what other components are involved here?  I might assume my problem is in lack of `systemd-resolved` knowledge, but where's the link to the erroneous `nmcli d` entry, and where is `systemd-resolved` configured by NM to use `1.1.1.1`?

Answer (score 0):

Even managed by systemd & NetworkManager you should be able to see the config with : `sudo systemd-analyze cat-config systemd/resolved.conf` where the /etc/systemd/resolved.conf contains the config to serve localhost on port 53. In this config you can use DOH (DNS over Https) or DOT (DNS over TLS).